# Fluid (stackable) content issues

Tags: html, css

I am building a fluid site comprised of 50% width divs and 25% width divs, the problem I am having is alignment, specifically with Chrome.

I have uploaded the code here: **http://tekulated.com/test100/**

`.half { float: left; width: 50%; }
.quater { float: left; width: 25%; }
.half img, .quater img { width: 100%; display: block; }`

If you load up the example in **Firefox** and resize the browser you will see it works perfectly. In **Chrome** however the divs grow unproportionately and as a result create large gaps.

~ Removing `display: block` corrects the problem however I get image padding issues.

Comment: Thank you for all the quick comments!

The large (red) image is 1000x600 and the small images are 500x300 -which I thought would fit perfectly?

Adding -1px bottom-margin to the large (red) image does correct the large gap issue but leaves me with 1px of empty space under that image... although tiny it isn't giving me the effect I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what's going on is that the big red box in your example gets a little too big compared to its row-mates and edges into the bottom row's area, which then pushes the boxes to the right, and then making the last box wrap to the next (logical) line

I think ensuring the big-red image is of a height proportional to the smaller row height would help. It's just an image resizing issue that's all.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup, adding a negative margin of 1px to the big red square will do the job on Chrome. Weird!

Comment: It's mostly just a rounding off error I think. And it happens because of the width being a percentage. Since the image's height is dependant on the constrained side, which is the width here, the image height has an off-by-one error at certain sizes

Comment: In FF it's 404.7px while in Chrome 405px. Lol.

Comment: Yup, that would be the little bugger that's causing all this mayhem :) Thanks for running that. Great work.